# Why does the value of a <textarea> reset when imported into another document?

Tags: javascript, html

The value of a `<textarea>` tag resets to its default value when imported into a new document.

```
var newDocument = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('New Document');
var textareaElement = document.getElementById('textarea');
var importedTextareaElement = newDocument.importNode(textareaElement, true);
newDocument.body.appendChild(importedTextareaElement);
console.log(textareaElement.value + ' vs ' + importedTextareaElement.value);
```

Does anyone know why this happens? I have the same issue with `<select>` tags. However, I do not have this issue with `<input>` tags, which maintain their values in new documents.

I am asking this question because I am trying to save part of the active DOM for later use. This means preserving the state of all elements, such as the value of radio selections, drop-down menus, and text input fields.

Comment: I feel like there may be a better way to do what you're trying to do. Why not simply restore the state of the element though? It's probably something about the import process.

Comment: Is it possible your <input>s are keeping their value because the value is specified with an attribute in the tag itself?  As opposed to entered by the the user after the document has been rendered?

Comment: In which browser do you see that behavior? `importNode` and `cloneNode` with the option `deep` should always create an exact copy of the current DOM. But they would not copy the properties. So if you change e.g. the elements value by typing something into it, this would not be copied, because this infos are then not part of the DOM. To see if everything is copied correctly you should test `textareaElement.innerHTML == importedTextareaElement.innerHTML` for `textarea` and `inputElement.getAttribute("value") == importedInputElement.getAttribute("value")`.

Comment: @Jonah None of the text `<input>` fields I've tested have their value attribute defined at any point of the test, but they still preserve their value when imported into a new document.

Comment: @t.niese I've tested this behaviour in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox. As stated in the original article, `<input>` fields preserve their value when imported into a new document, without any assistance from element attributes. Other input tags, such as `<textarea>` and `<select>` do not appear to preserve their value when imported into a new document. Personally, I consider this to be inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: @Bluecewe  While personally I would say, that user changed  `value` should not be copied at all if it is not reflected in the DOM, it is definitely an inconsistent behavior. I looked closer at this - reading the specs and browsing the issue tracker of FF - and there is still an open issue for FF [user input/selection not preserved on cloned HTML textarea and select elements](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=230307) and looking at the specs I'm still not sure whether the user changed value should be copied or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure "why" this is happening, but idiosyncracies like this in browsers are common. Work around it. From your code:

```
 var newDocument = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('New Document');
 var textareaElement = document.getElementById('textarea');
 var importedTextareaElement = newDocument.importNode(textareaElement, true);
 newDocument.body.appendChild(importedTextareaElement);
```

Do:

```
 importedTextareaElement.value = textareaElement.value;
```

I'd do this with all other elements as well, regardless of whether your test browser works for some of them.

Comment: Saving a state of form elements with `textareaElement.value` is the right way. Using `importNode` or `cloneNode` _copies_ the current state of the DOM but not changes that are done by e.g. typing something into textarea or input field. (_property_ vs _attribute_ of elements)

Comment: I could easily achieve the preservation of a single `<textarea>` value, but I am trying to preserve the values of numerous inputs in differently structured pages. In other words, I'm attempting to make the process dynamic, rather than bespoke to a particular page's structure.

Comment: @Bluecewe Write a series of functions for each of the from inputs. Then exploit them.